# Spring MVC Return in Snake Case

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I am stuck with something and need some help. Specifically, I have a POJO defined like this:

```
private String uid;
private String userName;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
```

My DAO looks something like:

```
@Override
public AAAUserCountDTO getUserCount(final String userName, final Date startDate, final Date endDate)
        throws BadParameterException {
    final String sql = "select uid, user_name, first_name, last_name from usage where user_name = :user_name and process_time >= :start_date and process_time < :end_date";

    final SqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("user_name", userName)
            .addValue("start_date", startDate).addValue("end_date", endDate);

    try {
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, namedParameters,
                new BeanPropertyRowMapper<DTO>(DTO.class).se);

    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
        throw new BadParameterException();
    }
}
```

I also have this set in my application yml file:

```
spring:
   application:
      name: Usage Service
   jackson:
      property-naming-strategy: CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES
```

My response is looking like:

```
uid: 1234,
userName: "Bob",
firstName: "Bob",
lastName: "Hopkins",
etc...
```

How can I enforce without having to tell each one in the JSON property notation as part of the POJO

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code helps:

```
@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(ObjectMapperConfigured event) {
    event.getObjectMapper().setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);        
}
```